# Hide html element if not post author - Wordpress, PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, code-snippets

New to PHP, struggling to complete a function snippet that would hide an html element on the post if the current user is not author.

This is what I have so far:

```
function post_hide_edit_button() {
    
   global $post, $current_user;
   
    if ( $post->post_author != $current_user->ID ) : ?>
      <style type="text/css">
          .post-edit-button   {
                display: none !important;
          }
      </style>;
    <?php endif;
}
post_hide_edit_button ();
```

I don't have any available hooks to use here or at least not sure what hook to use in this case.

I have tried ending the function with:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'post_hide_edit_button');
```

which worked for hiding the element, but then it messed up my header.

Is it possible to complete this snippet without a hook?

--------------- UPDATE ---------------

I found in another similar question an answer that mentions using:

```
add_action( 'loop_start', 'your_function' );
```

So I used that as `add_action( 'loop_start', 'post_hide_edit_button' );` in my function above and it works!

But is that the right way to go about it or will I end up with a similar issue to using the 'wp_head' hook at some point later?

Comment: I dont think you need it because different authors can't edit each other's content

Comment: Hey @uingtea, it's not about editing the author's content, it's about showing the 'Edit post' button to the others. Right now, I have an 'Edit post' button on my post that shows to all users. What I'm trying to achieve with this function is to hide the post edit button to all users except the author of the actual post.